# Frontity - How to display more than 10 blogs on blog page?

Tags: wordpress, frontity

I am trying to display all blog posts - over 100, but only 10 are being shown. i have tried to update the Settings > Reading in WP to show 100 posts, but it does not change the number of posts being shown through frontity. is there a default setting that I am not aware of?

Comment: No, there's not. But maybe the theme does ignore the setting from the backend and is set to a fixed amount of 10 posts. Does the behaviour change if you have less than 10 posts or something like 20?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I was able to solve this. In the WP functions.php, i added this snippet, and it allows for more than the default 10 posts:

```
add_filter( 'rest_post_query', 'se35728943_change_post_per_page', 10, 2 );

function se35728943_change_post_per_page( $args, $request ) {
    $max = max( (int) $request->get_param( 'custom_per_page' ), 200 );
    $args['posts_per_page'] = $max;    
    return $args;
}
```

JSON can be seen at /wp-json/wp/v2/posts?custom_per_page